# JDK 1.8 Comparator interface implementation issue on weblogic 12 server

Tags: java, java-8, weblogic

I have problems using comparator interface in JSP in sriptlet program , earlier I used JDK 1.6 and things were working fine and when I switched to JDK 1.8 on weblogic server 12 , The same comparator interface implemntation is now throwing exception for me . It states ,

> ******** must implement the inherited abstract method Comparator.thenComparingLong(ToLongFunction)
>
> *********must implement the inherited abstract method Comparator.thenComparingInt(ToIntFunction)
>
> ******* must implement the inherited abstract method Comparator.reversed()
>
> ********must implement the inherited abstract method Comparator.thenComparing(Function, Comparator)

And all those default function which has been since jdk 1.8 . how to resolve this issue? Please note compiler has been already used with JDK 1.8

Comment: “compiler has been already used with JDK 1.8” does not imply that the compiler is capable of working with Java 8 classes correctly. It might just happen to work unless you are using `default` methods. In the end, there is no alternative to using a real Java 8 compiler when using the JRE classes of Java 8.

Comment: So what should I do now? Do I need to implement all those default methods? If implements those comparator default method I got an another exception : -Cannot directly invoke the abstract method thenComparing(Comparator<? super Object>) for the type Comparator<Object>